# What's wrong with this limit?

Tags: limits

Let's say we have this limit:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x}$$
which is clearly 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0.$$
From there, to prove it we should:
$$\left\lvert \frac{1}{x} - 0 \right\rvert < \epsilon$$ 
(with $\epsilon > 0$ and small).

To solve that inequality we should deal with a system of:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x} &\lt \epsilon&&\text{(for }\frac{1}{x} \gt 0\text{)}\\
\frac{1}{x} &\gt -\epsilon&&\text{(for }\frac{1}{x}\lt 0\text{)}
\end{align*}$$
Then from the `()` we have that the first inequality is for $x < 0$ and the second is for $x > 0$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are dealing with a limit for $x \rightarrow +\infty$ we can assume that $x > 0$ and so we only need to consider $\frac{1}{x} < \epsilon$ which is equivalent to $x > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

So for any $\epsilon > 0$, for all $x > \frac{1}{\epsilon} (> 0)$ we have that $\lvert \frac{1}{x} - 0 \rvert < \epsilon$, as required.

[edit] The limit for $x \rightarrow \infty$ must mean (in our case) that $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists K>0: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}: ( \lvert x \rvert > K \rightarrow \lvert \frac{1}{x}  - 0 \rvert < \epsilon)$$

which is clear when we take $K = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: I didn't specified that $x \rightarrow +\infty$. $x \rightarrow \infty$ could be considered as $x \rightarrow +\infty$ and/or $x \rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: @CharliePigarelli: In that case I would write $\lvert x\rvert \to \infty$. This notation can be used in any normed vector space

Comment: @CharliePigarelli: That is very non-standard notation. $\infty$ and $+\infty$ are usually considered to be the same thing in calculus/real analysis.